# What does the notation $^{10} C_3$ mean? Or: I am confused by a birthday card...

Tags: notation, recreational-mathematics, natural-numbers

I've just seen a gift card on the internet that is supposedly for a mathematician's 21st birthday. It says

> $$ \text{Happy } ^{10} C_3 - 11\ln(e)-\frac{289}{3}+\left(\int_{\pi/6}^{\pi/3}\sec^2(x)dx\right)^2+7$$

I don't think I have ever seen the notation $^{10} C_3$ before. **What does it mean?**

Well,

$$ \left(\int_{\pi/6}^{\pi/3}\sec^2(x)dx\right)^2= \left(\tan(\pi/3)-\tan(\pi/6)\right)^2=\left(\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{1/3}\right)^2=4/3,$$

so I can simplify the expression that is wished to be happy to

$$ ^{10} C_3 - 11-\frac{289}{3}+4/3+7 = {}^{10} C_3 -99.$$

I guess the result is supposed to be 21, so (if I have not made any mistakes) I would expect that $${}^{10} C_3=120,$$ but I have absolutely no idea how to make sense of this...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

${}^{10} C_3$ means "$10$ choose $3$" and is more frequently denoted by the binomial coefficient $\binom{10}{3}$.

Comment: See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient#History_and_notation

Comment: Thanks! That was easy... Well, of course I know the binomial coefficient, but I have never seen that notation before. Is it commonly used (at least in English-speaking countries)?

Comment: Instead of "more frequently" say "in more advanced math".  That ${}^nC_r$ notation is probably in common use  in the US for ages 12 to 18 or so.  Along with a corresponding ${}^nP_r$ notation.  Called "combinations and permutations".

Comment: ... Here is an example: https://www.britannica.com/science/permutation

Comment: though in the Britannica example, $n$ is subscript rather than superscript, @GEdgar

Comment: Yes, the double subscript version ${}_nC_r$ is what I learned back in 1960-something.

Answer (score 1):

$$^{10}C_3 = {10 \choose 3} = \cfrac{10!}{7! 3!} = \cfrac{ \Gamma(11)}{\Gamma(8) \Gamma(4)} = 120 $$
You’ve guessed the right value.